# Why PHP + MySQL doesn't use file cache by default?

Tags: php, mysql, caching

It's much cheaper to retrieve data from the file rather than database if I understand correctly. So, why when we use `SELECT`, MySQL doesn't retrieve data from the file which would be created or updated everytime we use `UPDATE`, `INSERT`, `DELETE` etc? There reason is security issues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ask yourself: what *is* a database? It's a program that stores data, somehow, somewhere, and lets you retrieve it again. The database stores this data in files as well behind the scenes, somehow, somewhere. MySQL typically runs as a daemon. You contact that daemon and ask it for data. Where that data comes from is entirely up to MySQL. Many times it will retrieve this data out of RAM, which is *much less* expensive than opening a file and reading it from there. If the data does not happen to already be in RAM, *then* it will retrieve it from a file.

So, your question is misguided. MySQL *does* get the data from a file at some point. That is *not* necessarily "much cheaper" though. It may or may not be cheaper to get it from a database which keeps the data in RAM.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you would be interested in learning more about the MySQL Query Cache: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache.html

Answer (score 1):

MySQL normally is using some caching methods for queries (query cache) per default. Of course that cache is stored in memory ;)

Besides MySQL basically is retrieving data from a file already(depending on your table engine your whole database might be a single file), so...

Source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/query-cache-configuration.html

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is.  But you should use **Memcache** or **APC**, this way you can have expire times.  Not only that, when you update something in an admin panel for instance, you can delete a specific key that you specify to refresh that content on next load (hit the DB and save until next update or expire)

Answer (score 0):

If your using MySql as a Document store, rather then as a relational database, that your right that a 'select * from thing where id=123' *could* be quicker if written as 'file_get_contents("123.data")'

If your using MySql as a database, then 'select * from thing where name like "%doe%"' would become an 'open every file, check the name field, if matching add it to results, next file' which unless you have a trivial amount of data will be MUCH slower.  In addition any sort of join-like operation would become a headache as you write a relational database in php.

Answer (score 0):

It is not cheap to retrieve data from file rather than a database. Data in a database is also stored in a file but in an optimized way so the retrieval is much much faster. Here i am considering that the file and the data source lies in the same machine. In both cases the retrieval is I/O bounded.

If you want to cache properly you should use APC or Memcached or both. APC you can use as a local cache (store application configuration, language constants etc) whereas you can use memcached as a separate cache (user info, sessions etc).

Also you can use MySQL query cache, which btw is not a good idea if you have a decent write heavy application. Moreover query cache may stall your queries incase there are too many writes to your application because of waiting on query cache mutex.